# Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am compiling my c++ code. My requirement is to generate artifacts with two file. 
    1: Binary file
    2: Readme file
    I am able to generate a binary file, but I am unable to generate a readme file in a specific format. Readme file contains build number in below format
    buildnumber = $a.$d.$e 
    $a=  build pipeline variable that can be set ,
    $d =some incremental value, 
    $e =git commit SHA like 669b7f8e

I don't want to use power shell “##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number”and put value.

my pipeline is :

```
    variables:
      - name: Version
        value: 1
      - name: VersionRevision
        value: $[counter(variables['Version'], 0)]
      - name: commitsha
        value: $['Build.SourceVersion']
      - name: build
        value: mybuild
      - name: buildnumber
        value: $[ format('{0}.{1}.{2}', variables['build'], variables['VersionRevision'],variables['commitsha']) ]

trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: gcctest
  pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - script: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
  - script: g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost/asio -I/usr/include/boost -o result.out m.cpp
          c.cpp d.cpp f.cpp 

  - bash: echo $(buildnumber)>test.txt
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      contents: '?(*.out|*.txt)'
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
        pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        artifactName: result
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use a powershell script? The inline version would do that easily for you.

Comment: Thanks, @MarTin, I am coming from bash background, I don't have much idea of PowerShell, would you edit my script, where I need to change. Also, a challenge is that I want the first 8 characters of commit hash in the readme file. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: When you have the SHA1 in a variable as a string use `$sha.substring(0,8)` to get the first 8 chars of the commit id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that inside on a inline PowerShell script task:

```
$text = "$($build).$($VersionRevision).$($commitsha)"
Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow
$text > "readme.txt"
```

[image: PowerShell Script Task]

Keep in mind that you have to define `$build`, `$VersionRevision` and `$commitsha` before or you add the definition inside of the PowerShell script.

Comment: @VijayVerma it's hard to read your unfomatted answer. Try to format codelines as code. Which error you get?

Comment: this is code i changed 
`- powershell:
       $commitId= "$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION"

       $definitionName= "$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME"

       $shortId= $commitId.Substring(1, 8)

       $buildName=$definitionName+$shortId
       $text=$buildName
       echo $text
      Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow
      $text > 'readme.txt'
 - bash: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName">test.txt`

Comment: Please find the formatted code.
[link](https://codeshare.io/2E9NJ8). My simple requirements are as below. When any commit changes build will trigger and generate 2 file binary and redme.txt.
 buildnumber = $a.$d.$e $a= build pipeline variable that can be set , $d =some incremental value, $e =git commit SHA like 669b7f8e
Read.txt contain

Comment: @VijayVerma looks good, so I understand it correct, there are no issues left?

Comment: Now I have to build a release pipeline using the build artifacts:
thanks "Martin"
My target is building a docker image with the mentioned task
○ based on Ubuntu 16.04
○ must contain Build artifacts from the build pipeline.
I have experience in building docker image , but how to perform in azure devops not sure. Any pointer will be much appreciated

Comment: @VijayVerma I have also no expirence with docker & azure. I think the best way is to mark this question as solved by clicking the checkmark next to my answer and open a new question about that specific subject.